Children route parameter are not set with withComponentInputBinding
In an Angular 18 application I can not have children route parameter set.
I have a route defined as
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'test',
    children: [
       { path: ':operation/:id', component: CrudComponent },
       { path: ':operation', component: CrudComponent},
       { path: '', component: CrudComponent }
    ], component: TestComponent},

and in app.config.ts
  export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
   providers: [provideRouter(routes,  withComponentInputBinding()),

in test.component.html
<a [routerLink]="['/test']">no operation</a>-
<a [routerLink]="['/test','onlyoperation']">only operation</a>-
<a [routerLink]="[ '/test','operationNid','123']">operation and id</a>
   <hr/>operation={{operation}}   id={{id}}  

and in test.component.ts
  @Input() operation:string="";
  @Input() id:number=0;

I expected to see the values shown by "operation={{operation}}   id={{id}}", but they remain blank.
If I define the following routes, it works as expected
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'test/:operation/:id', component: TestComponent },
  { path: 'test/:operation', component: TestComponent },
  { path: 'test', component: TestComponent},

where am I wrong?

The @Input you define works when you set it directly on the route :operation/:id, so only then it has access to the input binding, else it doesn't.
You have to look for other methods to access these properties from the parent.
You can listen for route changes, then watch for the params change, this is what gets binded to @Input.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule, CommonModule],
  template: `
    <a [routerLink]="['/test']">no operation</a>-
    <a [routerLink]="['/test','onlyoperation']">only operation</a>-
    <a [routerLink]="[ '/test','operationNid','123']">operation and id</a>
      <hr/>operation={{operation | json}}   id={{id | json}}  
      <hr/>
      <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class TestComponent {
  navigationSub!: Subscription;
  operation = '';
  id = 0;
  activateRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);
  router = inject(Router);

  ngOnInit() {
    this.navigationSub = this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((e): e is NavigationEnd => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((value) => {
        const { operation, id } =
          this.activateRoute?.snapshot.firstChild?.params || {};
        this.operation = operation;
        this.id = id;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.navigationSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
